# Google Play - Android app not showing up in the store for specific phone model although being present in the apps Device Catalog

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-play, google-play-console

### Background

I'm having an issue with users not finding or and not being able to install my app on Google Play. Samsung Galaxy S9, OnePlus 3T, Sony Xperia XZ2 are some of the models where I know this is happening. I'm assuming those models use Android API level 28 (Pie) which was released in August 2018.

The app is created with Ionic Framework (Cordova).

```
Cordova:
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : not available

Android SDK Tools : 
   26.1.1 (C:/Users/maxim/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk)
```

### What I've tried

I first checked the Device Catalog in Google Play Developer Console to see that those models were listed as compatible, which they were.

I then noticed that my config.xml specified a maxSdkVersion for the Android app. I removed that and published the new version. It's now been two days since, I can see the new app version in Google Play, but it still won't show up on those newer models.

Here are the relevant pieces of information from the store listing:

- **Updated**: February 19, 2019
- **Current Version**: 1.0.25
- **Requires Android**: 4.4 and up

Also, in Developer Console, it says:

- **Features**: android.hardware.faketouch, android.hardware.microphone

### Question

Where do I begin checking why this is occurring? How can I see what devices are actually supported?

Comment: Add latest version of android in ionic project.

Comment: You mean `ionic cordova platform remove android` and then `ionic cordova platform add android`?

Comment: Yes, show me status result of "ionic info"

Comment: Added it to my question.

Comment: yes. it is latest version(cordova-android 8.0.0) which support android 8 or android sdk 28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking with Google Play Developer Support, they pointed out that there was a conflict in the AndoidManifest.xml file, which temporarily made some devices incompatible.

I went into the AndroidManifest.xml file and removed any `<uses-sdk>` and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update your cordova version.
on mac `sudo npm update -g cordova`

1. ionic cordova rm android
2. ionic cordova add android
3. all done